# What is the best way to join callback functions into a single callback?

Tags: javascript, callback

Given the JavaScript code:

```
self.queue.now( 'test_1', function() {
    self.queue.now( 'test_2', done )
})
```

.. where the `now` fn() has a callback argument, what is the best way to combine / join the callbacks so that the code is no longer nested?  Specifically, I would like to have the `self.queue.now` calls be on the same indentation level and when both are finished, only then, would `done()` be called.

Comment: Use an ES7 transpiler and `async` `await`. Everything else will need callbacks, with indentation.

Comment: you could use the async library's parallel : https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel to do something like async.parallel([firstAsyncFunction, secondAsyncFunction, function done() { //both async functions are done at this point  }])

Comment: I think both solutions would certainly work.  Will give them a shot.  Thanks Bergi and @officert

Answer (score 0):

Solution ended up leveraging async.parallel:

```
async.parallel( [
    function( cb ) {
        self.queue.now( 'test_1', cb )
    },
    function( cb ) {
        self.queue.now( 'test_2', cb )
    }
], done )
```

Although it would have been nice to not have the `function( cb )` wrappers ..